# Laravel excel - when i use multiplesheets i have some error with sheets name

Tags: php, laravel, phpexcel, laravel-excel

[image][image]

```
<?php

namespace App\Exports;

use Illuminate\Contracts\View\View;
use Maatwebsite\Excel\Concerns\FromView;
use Maatwebsite\Excel\Concerns\WithTitle;
use Maatwebsite\Excel\Concerns\ShouldAutoSize;

class ExportReports implements FromView, ShouldAutoSize, WithTitle
{
    public function __construct($courseItems, $data, $title)
    {
        $this->courses = $courseItems;
        $this->data = $data;
        $this->title = $title;
    }

    public function title(): string
    {
        $queryString = str_replace(array('/', '\n', '?', '*', '[', ']'), '', trim($this->title));
        return 'lol';
    }

    public function view(): View
    {
        $data = $this->data;
        $courses = $this->courses;
        return view('reports.excel.programm', compact('data', 'courses'));
    }

}
```

When i use multiple sheets in laravel-excel i lost sheets title and have error like
Error in some part data Report.xlsx do u want restore it? are u sure ?

```
public function sheets(): array
    {
        $sheets = [];
        foreach ($this->data as $key => $value) {
            $sheets[] = new ExportReports($value['courses'], $value['items'], $value['title']);
        }

        return $sheets;
    }
```

is it right too use loop in sheets?

Comment: please provide the error provided in english, so that everyone can understand

Comment: @bhucho done, sorry for previous imgs

Comment: which version of laravel excel you use?

Comment: @Kusy 3.1 laravel excel ( last version )